# SWR: Revalidate stale resources without refetching on every mount

Tags: javascript, typescript, swr

I use SWR with a globally configured axios fetcher like this

```
    <SWRConfig
              value={{
                fetcher: getFetcher,
              }}
            > ...
```

I don't want to refetch on every component mount, so I have disabled `revalidateIfStale`. So far so good.

I sometimes want to revalidate a key (get fresh data in the background without a loading-state) and for this I can use `mutate` from the `useSWR`-hook or even just import `mutate` directly from SWR. So far so good.

Now the problem is when the resource in question is loaded at some point, but not currently mounted. `mutate` then does nothing, which technically makes sense because it probably doesn't know what to do, but from how I want it to work it really sucks that I as a developer have to know whether a certain resource is currently mounted or not to be able to choose the right method of invalidating the cache.

How can I have SWR cache stuff without revalidating on every single mount while still having one simple way of invalidating resources?
I realize it sounds like I want `invalidateIfStale` to be true, and I maybe I do. But I don't want resources to be fetched on every mount.

What are my options?

Thanks